# enforce https request on a non https website - Mixed Content error in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, https, load-balancing

This might be a weird case, and feel free to let me know if there is better way in general.

So I have an application with a load balancer. The load balancer takes in HTTPs only traffic. So far so good.

The load balancer then sends it as HTTP to my asp.netcore.

What it implies :

- Although the access to the website is in Https, the asp.netcore app doesn't know about it.
- I only specify it as HTTPs in Development environment as I have my cookies in HTTPS only

But that gives me this problem :

> Mixed Content: The page at 'pagePath' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure manifest 'path/site.webmanifest'. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Here is my startup

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
    app.UseMiddleware<WebRequestLoggerMiddleWare>();
    app.UseMiddleware<UserTimeZoneMiddleWare>();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

And my cookie policy, still in statup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login/");
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/forbidden/");
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(cookieSettings.CookieExpirationInHours);
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

    });
```

What would be the best way to make sure the webmanifest is requested through HTTPS ?

Should I just force the whole website to be HTTPS and route traffic from the LB as https? That's one way, but it shouldn't be necessary...

Comment: `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`is only enabled in development mode, you should put it after the if/else part. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1#changes-to-startup for a correct Startup.cs after migration to 2.1

Comment: As mentioned in the post, this is a solution to enforce https in the web site, but for now, it's not as only the load balancer is through HTTPS, then passing queries through HTTP to the server.
So I'm looking a for a different solution.

Comment: UseHsts will set the https strict policy (via headers) for browser supporting it will always call the https endpoint, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts. UseHttpsRedirection will redirect the users **first** request to the https endpoint. It doesnt matter if your reverse proxy calls your application with http or https not, as long as your reverse proxy correctly sets `X-Forwarded-*`  headers

Comment: The `X-Forwarded-` headers tell ASP.NET Core whether or not the original request was on http or https (`X-Forwarded-Proto`), whats the original client ip (`X-Forwarded-For`) etc.

Comment: Also how do you generate your urls? are they hardcoded? Mvc via `~/path/...`? If you hard code them for any reason, you can use `//example.com/` instead of `http://example.com`. This will use the protocol used on which the page was originally called. The url generation tools should generate urls with proper protocol as long as the ForwardedFor middleware is active (which it should be by default)

Comment: Also see [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insights! I always use src="~/path/to/file". Double thanks for the link!

Comment: Could you create an answer so I can validate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traffic between your reverse proxy and your ASP.NET Core application doesn't have to be encrypted via https, but two conditions have to be met so your ASP.NET Core application knows if the original HTTP Request was came over https or http.

1. Your reverse proxy has to Send the correct headers with the original protocol and IP of the original host. The default headers for that are `X-Forwarded-For` for the remote IP and `X-Forwarded-Proto` for the protocol
2. The forwarded headers middleware is set up by default when running on IIS and (according to the docs) needs to be enabled for other hosting scenarios.

The documentation can be read under [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> {
>     services.AddMvc();
>
>     services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
>     {
>         options.ForwardedHeaders = 
>             ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
>     });
> }
>
> public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
> {
>     app.UseForwardedHeaders();
>
>     if (env.IsDevelopment())
>     {
>         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
>     }
>
>     app.UseStaticFiles();
>     // In ASP.NET Core 1.x, replace the following line with: app.UseIdentity();
>     app.UseAuthentication();
>     app.UseMvc();
> }
> ```

If your proxy names headers differently than `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host`, you can use the `ForwardedForHeaderName`, `ForwardedProtoHeaderName` and `ForwardedHostHeaderName` properties on `ForwardedHeadersOptions` to change it.

Additionally your `Startup` class should look like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    // redirect to Https
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

as per official examples and to ensure the user is redirected to http on his/her first visit, [HSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#http-strict-transport-security-protocol-hsts) should handle consecutive requests